# Databricks file trigger - how to whitlelist storage firewall

Tags: azure, networking, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Recently, Databricks added a new feature - [file trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/file-arrival-triggers).
However, this functionality seems to need a storage account to allow all network traffic.

My storage account has a firewall configured, it denies traffic from unknown sources. Databricks Workspace is deployed to our internal network - we are using Vnet injection. All necessary subnets are whitelisted, generally, storage works fine, but not with a file trigger.
If I turn off the storage firewall, the file trigger works fine.
External location and Azure Databricks Connector are configured correctly.

The error I get:

> Invalid credentials for storage location abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/. The credentials for the external location in the Unity Catalog cannot be used to read the files from the configured path. Please grant the required permissions.

If I look at the logs in my storage account - it looks like the file trigger lists the storage account from a private IP address starting from 10.120.x.x.
How do I whitelist this service? I want to keep my storage under the firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 3rd April 2023rd: ADLS firewall isn't supported right now out of the box, work is in progress to solve this issue.

It's described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities#--recommended-for-vnet-injected-workspaces-configure-trusted-access-to-azure-storage-based-on-your-managed-identity) - you need:

- Create managed identity by creating the Databricks Access Connector
- Give this managed identity permission to access your storage account
- Create UC external location using the managed identity
- Give access to your storage account to given access connector - in "Networking", select "Resource instances", then select a Resource type of `Microsoft.Databricks/accessConnectors` and select your Azure Databricks access connector.

Comment: Hello Alex, This is already done. 
I can use this storage account for other tasks without any issues. 
The only option that doesn't work is a file trigger.

Comment: That’s interesting - I need to check that with dev team…

Comment: updated post - it's a current limitation :-(

Comment: cool, thanks for the information. 
hope it will be fixed at some point

Answer (score 0):

According to [Databricks Monthly Customer Newsletter (Feb 2024)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/product/2024/february#file-arrival-triggers-in-azure-databricks-workflows-is-ga) and this issue is fixed in GA.

*File arrival triggers is now generally available in all cloud providers. With this release, you can use file arrival triggers to run a Azure Databricks job when new files arrive in a Unity Catalog volume in addition to the existing support for Unity Catalog external locations. See Trigger jobs when new files arrive.*

*This release also removes a limitation with using **file arrival triggers with an Azure firewall**.*